# How to trigger automatic page scroll on a particular page position with sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to create a interactive web comic (in html, css and javascript) where I want to trigger an automatic page scroll down at a defined speed from one point to another point, to make a sequential animation using multiple jpg images.

In simple words, when a reader scrolls and reaches a certain (my already defined) position of a page, the page automatically force scrolls the page further down at a pre-defined point.

Exactly like they did in this web toon: http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=350217&no=31

I also want to trigger the sound effects, just like they did in the above mentioned link...

I tried to accomplish this using the following script, but was unable to control the start and stop position for the scroll. Plus I also want it to scroll only once on a single page load.

```js
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript1.2>
//change 1 to another integer to alter the scroll speed. Greater is faster

var speed=1

var currentpos=0,alt=1,curpos1=0,curpos2=-1

function initialize(){

startit()

}

function scrollwindow(){

if (document.all &&

!document.getElementById)

temp=document.body.scrollTop

else

temp=window.pageYOffset

if (alt==0)

alt=2

else

alt=1

if (alt==0)

curpos1=temp

else

curpos2=temp

if (curpos1!=curpos2){

if (document.all)

currentpos=document.body.scrollTop+speed

else

currentpos=window.pageYOffset+speed

window.scroll(0,currentpos)

}

else{

currentpos=0

window.scroll(0,currentpos)

}

}

function startit(){

setInterval("scrollwindow()",50)

}

window.onload=initialize

</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic auto scroll function which will trigger when the user scrolls past 300px.

```
var scroll = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {

        var position = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(position);

        if(position > 300 && position < 400 && scroll==true ) {
            scroll = false;

            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollTo").offset().top
            },2000);

        }
    })
```

**EDIT**

At the moment it is a once time thing, however if you add this if statement after the first if statement it will reset the scroll state to true and will allow it to run again.

```
if (position > 0 && position < 300 && scroll==false) {
        scroll = true;   
    }
```

**EDIT**

To get sound to play you can use the new the .play command and just add it to what happens in the IF statement, here is an example of the .play code;

```
$('#videoId').get(0).play();
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code working not by setting a position but it finding the divs position - here is it working in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3fxcbs2k/3/

```
    var scroll = true;

$(window).scroll(function (e) {

    var position = $(document).scrollTop();
    var startP = $("#scrollTOO").position();
    var finishP = $("#scrollTo");

    if(position > startP.top && startP.top+100 && scroll==true ) {
        scroll = false;

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: finishP.offset().top},2000);

    } if (position > 0 && position < 300 && scroll==false) {
        scroll = true;   
    }
})
```

To set the position you want it to start scrolling change the value of

```
var startP = $("      ").position();
```

Then to set the finish position  change the value of

```
var finsihP = $("      ");
```

**Audio**

```
<audio id="sound">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

var scroll = true;

$(window).scroll(function (e) {

```
var position = $(document).scrollTop();
var startP = $("#scrollTOO").position();
var finishP = $("#scrollTo");
```

Jquery play looks like - `$('#sound').get(0).play();`

So just add it to the what happens when triggered, like below.

```
    if(position > startP.top && startP.top+100 && scroll==true ) {
        scroll = false;

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: finishP.offset().top},2000);
        $('#sound').get(0).play();

    } if (position > 0 && position < 300 && scroll==false) {
        scroll = true;   
    }
})
```

**To make more do the following**

Think of the var as id tags which can be called upon later in the code and after the = is there values for example;

```
var startP = $("#scrollTOO").position();
```

startP is the vars unique name, and its value is the div with the id of scrollTOO position.

So to make more start and end points you will have to make more vars 1 start and one end point. Example;

```
var startP = $("#scrollTOO").position();
var finishP = $("#scrollTo");

var startP2 = $("#point2").position();
var finishP2 = $("#pint2");
```

and then its just to make another if statement, the same as before but replace the start points and end points,

```
if(position > startP2.top && startP2.top+100 && scroll==true ) {
            scroll = false;

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: finishP2.offset().top},2000);
```

However because we have it so it will only trigger once will have to make more var scrolls, 1 for each one.

```
var scroll = true;    
var scroll2 = true;
var scroll3 = true;
var scroll4 = true;
```

and then each if statement will have to look for the relevant scroll for example the second scroll if statement will look like.

```
if(position > startP2.top && startP2.top+100 && scroll2==true ) {
scroll2 = false;
```

Comment: Does the above script requires jquery for it? Coz I tried adding it to my embedded .js script of the page and it didn't work after the 300px as it should. I also added it normally using the <script> tag didn't work.. Plus can you please elaborate the sound play function. How can I trigger a particular mp3 or ogg or wav file to play along with the scroll?? For example the sound file name is 1.mp3

Comment: @CodyCodes I think I did it in <script> tags at the bottom of the page, it might sound silly but make sure you have link your jQuery API both swell

Comment: @CodyCodes here is a JSFiddle with it working so you can see the code to make sure you have it correct, https://jsfiddle.net/3fxcbs2k/1/

Comment: Follow up question, do I have to add another div to determine the ScrollTo position (upto where the page will auto scroll), coz I need to put up a start and end point of the auto scroll. Btw I tried with jquery and adding it at the bottom of the page with <script> tag it still doesn't work.. :(

Comment: im not sure why it isn't working, best to add it to a .js and link it like <script src="........"></script>. What do you mean to determine the scrollTop position?

Comment: Can you show me how can I make my code (the code I shown in my initial question) to trigger at a div and end at another div.. Since its working for me, all I need to figure out is how to control its triggering positions..

Comment: @CodyCodes I have added a new edit, all the code you need and instructions on how to set which div to use as start and end points are in there. Anymore problems just let me know, however going to sleep so won't be able to answer until the morning

Comment: Hey.. Finally it worked.. Thanks, I was putting the divs wrong. Now one final thing, can you please tell me how to trigger a sound autoplay from an .mp3 file, exactly at the time of the autoscroll..?

Comment: @CodyCodes I've never done this but give me a few mins, i'll work it out

Comment: @CodyCodes I have updated my answer, the code you need is at the bottom

Comment: THANK YOU EVER SOO MUCH.. Everything works!!! Now if I want to add more than one start and end point, can I simply use the scrollTOO and scrollTo divs twice or have to add it in the <script> tag?

Comment: @CodyCodes you will have to create new ids and vars, its not to hard, if you get stuck let me know

Comment: @CodyCodes i have updated the question exampling what vars are and how to add more.